# Add mongo extension to php.ini

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using ubuntu and want to add mongo extension to php.ini but don't exactly know where to add the line `extension=mongo.so`

Comment: You can add near with other extensions written

Comment: read this http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-install-up-mongodb-and-php-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Well you can add this line at the very end of php.ini file.

Comment: it has to go below where extension_dir is defined

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on ubuntu 
Run this command

```
gksudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

once the file get opened save this line in the file

```
extension=mongo.so
```

for more Read this http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-install-up-mongodb-and-php-on-ubuntu/

Comment: It said that can't find the file /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini.How to solve it?

Comment: Read the link I have given you. Complete installation guide.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put this line (`extension=mongo.so`) inside (at the end worked for me) your `php.ini` file. 
If you don't know where your `php.ini` file is, you can display its location using this following line : `echo phpinfo();` (from a php page of your project). Look at the line "Loaded Configuration File".