# how can i fix tihs :PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mongodb.so'

Tags: php, mongodb

how can i fix this

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mongodb.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php7/modules/mongodb.so (/usr/lib/php7/modules/mongodb.so: undefined symbol: ns_parserr), /usr/lib/php7/modules/mongodb.so.so (/usr/lib/php7/modules/mongodb.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory))

Comment: You can try to edit your php.ini to find the library and uncomment its activation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171001/add-mongo-extension-to-php-ini

Comment: mongodb.so: undefined symbol: ns_parserr u know what mean of this?

Comment: sadly no...sorry

Comment: @Monnomcjo Surely, if the extension was commented in the `php.ini` then the error could not happen as PHP woudl not be trying to load the extension.

Comment: Did you also install the MongoDB server as well as put the `mongodb.so` file into the `ext` folder under your PHP

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to load dynamic library 'mongodb.so' - Debian 8 , PHP 7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51078247/unable-to-load-dynamic-library-mongodb-so-debian-8-php-7-2)

Comment: Any luck resolving this, as I am having the precise same issue?